# Org-Mode links opening in new splits?

Tags: org-mode, doom, window-splitting, org-roam

I'm a bit stuck. I want to open new splits (windows within a frame to be precise) with each link I'm visiting. A bit like going down the rabbit hole.

What I have is `1 | 2` and it bounces back between the two.
What I want is `1 | 2 | 3 | n` so each time I hit `enter` on a link, it visits the link in a new split. Vertical splits in my case.

The recommended setup from the Org-Roam GitHub.

```lisp
(setq org-link-frame-setup '((file . find-file-other-window)))
```

What I've tried so far

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-follow-link-hook #'+evil/window-vsplit-and-follow)
(setq org-link-frame-setup '((file . find-file-other-window)))
```

> Result: Opens 3 splits with the same buffer. One larger, two half that size each.

```lisp
(setq org-link-frame-setup '((file . (lambda (file) (select-window (split-window-right)) (find-file file)))))
```

> Result: No influence on behaviour at all.

###### Emacs Version

Emacs 27.2 (Emacs-Plus) with Doom Emacs 3.0.0-pre

I'm hoping someone here has a better idea to achieve this than I had.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info